# Silex + Twig + SQL Server : rendering pictures

Tags: database, image, twig, silex

I have some pictures in a SQL Server database in a BLOB column.

I need to get them and show up to the HTML page.

But in the result on the HTML page, I have the long string in `src` attribute instead of the pictures.

Silex code:

```
<!-- language-all: php -->
$pict->get('/show_pic/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
        //Request of photos
        $photos=getPhotoByID($id, $app);
        return $app['twig']->render('test/template_show_pictures.html.twig', array('photos'=>$photos));
})->bind('show_pic');

function getPhotoByID($ID, $app)
{
        $sql = "<some SQL here>";
        $statement = $app['dbs']['mssql']->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindValue(1, $ID, "text");
        $statement->execute();
        $photo = $statement->fetchAll();

        if (empty($photo)) {
            return "We don't have a photo with id=".$ID;
        }

        return $photo;
}
```

Twig file:

```
<!-- language: twig -->
    {% extends 'test/test_base.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %}Pictures from DB{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% for im in photos %}
      <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ im['Foto'] }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

HTML markup :

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pictures from DB</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css">
        </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page">
      <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,���JFIF...too many symbols here" />
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode image with base64

Add filter for encoding to base64:

```
$app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addFilter('base64_encode', new \Twig_SimpleFilter('base64_encode', function ($value) {
        return \base64_encode($value);
    }));

    return $twig;
});
```

And use it in template:

```
{{ im['Foto']|base64_encode }}
```